# Does the iOS Networking Framework (NSURLCache) transparently handle ETags?

Tags: ios, etag, nsurlcache

We are wondering, whether `NSURLCache` transparently handles `ETag` based caching headers.

**Asked differently:** If correctly setting up `NSURLCache`, will the iOS networking framework automatically "remember `ETags` per request URI" and add them to request headers once a request for the exact same URI is submitted?

Or does the iOS developer have to handle `ETags` manually, from storing a map of request URIs to response `ETags` and including those on subsequent requests on handling 304 responses?

Comment: It looks like you might be better off asking this in the Apple developer forums where there area Apple engineers present.

Comment: You can find an answer for this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659764/nsurlcache-and-etags